# Auto clicker with a simple GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

What do you think of my auto clicker script? Even though it's just for my own personal use, I'm thinking of using PyInstaller to turn it into an exe, so I know how to do that in the future.

```
import pyHook, threading
import tkinter as tk    
from pyautogui import click

t1token = 0
threadsRun = 1
ac = 0

def simplegui():

    def sunken():
        """keep startButton lowered and disabled.
            hook keyboard, start clicks function"""
        global threadsRun
        startButton.config(relief=tk.SUNKEN, state=tk.DISABLED, 
                           text="r=stop listening")
        hm.HookKeyboard()
        threadsRun = 1
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=clicks, args=(startButton,), 
                              name='clicks{}'.format(t1token))
        t1.start()

    def destroy():
        """exit program"""
        global threadsRun, ac
        ac = 0
        threadsRun = 0
        # Not sure if keyboard unhooks if press quit after press start
        root.destroy()

    startButton = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=sunken, 
                            height=10, width=20)
    startButton.grid(row=1, column=0)

    quitButton = tk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=destroy, 
                           height=10, width=20)
    quitButton.grid(row=1, column=1)

def clicks(startButton):
    """right clicks the mouse at 1k clicks per minute
        also puts button back to normal state once done"""
    global t1token
    while threadsRun:
        while ac:
            click(clicks=17, interval=0.06, button='right')
    t1token += 1
    startButton.config(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.NORMAL, text="Start")

root = tk.Tk()

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    """A key was pressed"""
    global threadsRun, ac
    if event.Key == "R":
        ac = 0
        threadsRun = 0
        hm.UnhookKeyboard()
        return False
    if event.Key == "T":
        ac = not ac
        return False
    return True

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
simplegui()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you link to the modules please as I cant ```pip install``` them in command prompt

Comment: @DanHowe I'd try `pip install pyhook3 pyautogui`, as the `pyhook` package hasn't been updated since 2008. I can't vouch for any of these packages though.